How do I prevent Python xmltodict from generating this additional list while converting from xml to dictionary?
The structure of the XML is as following:
<jobs>
  <job>
  ...
  </job>
</jobs>

If there is more than one job element within jobs, the library xmltodict generates an additional list. around all jobs.
In case of multiple jobs:
{'jobs': {'job': [{ job1 }, { job2 }]}}

In case of one job:
{'jobs': {'job': { job1 }}}

How do I prevent this from happening because it messes up my code in displaying the job(s) on a website?
I already tried to convert the dictionary to a string and removing the []. But there has to be a more elegant solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
